# How to make a float show up with 2 decimal points in Python (e.g. show 8.60 instead of 8.6)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm making a tip calculator in Python, and it basically works now except I want to make the resulting tip amount show up with 2 decimals, including forcing a 0 in there if necessary (so like $8.50 instead of $8.5).

I've tried searching for the problem and think I have to incorporate %.02f somehow, but can't figure out where to put it.

Code below:

```
bill = input("How much did your bill come out to?  ")

bill2 = float(bill.strip("$"))
#created a new 'bill2' variable to strip any $ from the input and ensure it's a float

tip15 = round (bill2 * 0.15, 4)
tip18 = round (bill2 * 0.18, 4)
tip20 = round (bill2 * 0.20, 4)

print("\nYou should tip your chosen percentage from the following...", 
    "\n\n15%: $" + str(tip15), 
    "\n18%: $" + str(tip18), 
    "\n20%: $" + str(tip20),
    "\n")
```

Comment: https://pyformat.info/#number_padding

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following in order to have two decimals point.

```
print("%.2f" % 8.5)
>>>8.50
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm not sure where to put that script in the above code?